# Javascript and defaultValue of hidden input elements

Tags: javascript, dom

Assume you have input element:

```
<input id="aaa" type="text" value="unchanged" />
```

Then launch js script:

```
var e = document.getElementById("aaa");
e.value = "changed";
alert(e.defaultValue + "/" + e.value);
```

Result will be "unchanged/changed". Unfortunately, when your input element is `hidden`:

```
<input id="aaa" type="hidden" value="unchanged" />
```

...the same js script seem not to be working any more. Result is "changed/changed".
Is this a proper way? If so, why only hidden form elements act different?

Comment: What browser are you working with?

Comment: from my testing, @Pointy answer sums up the situation correctly

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The "defaultValue" property is only maintained in a way you apparently expect for "text", "file", and "password" fields.

[Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-6043025) is the relevant portion of the DOM spec.

I suspect the reason for this is that user activity on its own cannot change the value of hidden elements. If you want to preserve the initial values, run something at "load" or "ready" to stash the value somewhere.

Comment: I managed to solve it by changing it to `type="input" style="display: none"` and that works for me. I was just curious about specification and reason. Thanks for answer!

Comment: not only that, seems none new types, eg, type='number', type='time', etc, keep `defaultValue`!  to me, this means keeping my own attribute to do what I was using `defaultValue` to do.  oh well

Answer (score 3):

For hidden input elements, defaultValue **isn't actually implemented**. The reason why you get the same result ast `.value` is because the browser your using is just defaulting.

See [here](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=1787115) for a discussion of this with Firefox.