# How can I use defaultValue with hidden element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I copy the example of the existing Understand me

```
<input id="aaa" type="text" value="unchanged" />

var e = document.getElementById("aaa");
e.value = "changed";
alert(e.defaultValue + "/" + e.value);
```

Result will be "unchanged/changed". Unfortunately, when your input element is hidden:

```
<input id="aaa" type="hidden" value="unchanged" />
```

..the same js script seem not to be working any more. Result is "changed/changed".

So an ineffective way to compare and they are today 
please..

Comment: Is your question a copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319678/javascript-and-defaultvalue-of-hidden-input-elements ?

Comment: yes, But then again because I can't be solved ....-0- i want try to compare hidden value,,, sorry I use a translator

Comment: It's well explained in the duplicated question: default value can be used reliably with "text", "file", and "password" fields. Check this spec for reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-6043025 If you want to ask new question then don't duplicate existing, in your case you could ask "How can I use defaultValue with hidden element" and people would suggest you some workarounds.

Comment: oh sorry Today, using first I did not know well.
Thanks I'll attention

Comment: I modified,Thank you